# application has stopped unexpectedly Intent android studio

Tags: android-intent

I have a problem the application has stopped unexpectedly android studio when I use Intent. Can you help me?

```
Button przegladaj=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonPrzegladaj);
przegladaj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), lprzegladaj.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Comment: AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: : android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class ; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: i've declared this activity

Comment: you have to declare both the activity .are you define both the activity in manifest

Comment: hee your devleration is wrong :<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="Layouty.lprzegladaj"
            android:label="Przegladaj" />
    </activity> try this you forgot to closing tag for Mainactivty

Comment: and try Mainactivity.this at the place of getApplicationContext()

Comment: and provide full package name for your second activity or define by only activity name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unable to find explicit activity class ; have you declared this
>   activity in your AndroidManifest.xml

It seems like you not yet declared your activity in `AndroidMinfest.xml`

Make sure you have declared

`<activity android:name="lprzegladaj"></activity>` inside application tag.

If you have package name for your activity, declara like this   `<activity android:name=".YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.lprzegladaj"></activity>`